# PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"

Tags: java, postgresql

I have started to get the exception since I configured timestamp comparing. I can't see where the problem can be. The query runs completely fine in a separate query console:

```java
@Query(value = "select * from notifications n " +
       "where n.time_stamp < (now() at time zone 'Europe/Moscow' - interval :seconds second) order by n.time_stamp desc limit :limit",
       nativeQuery = true)
List<Notification> getNotificationList(@Param("seconds") Integer seconds,
                                       @Param("limit") Integer limit);
```

Also have tried doing the same thing like this:

```
@Query(value = "select * from moneta_notification_resend_info n " +
        "where n.time_stamp < (now() at time zone 'Europe/Moscow' - interval ?1 second) order by n.time_stamp desc limit ?2",
        nativeQuery = true)
List<MonetaNotificationResendInfo> getResendInfoList(Integer seconds,
                                                     Integer limit);
```

the same error popped up

Comment: Can  you try ` interval :seconds 'second' )`

Comment: @jian just tried it, the same error popped up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `interval` keyword requires a constant, you can't pass the string after that dynamically.

There are two ways to build an `interval` dynamically:

```
make_interval(secs => :seconds)
```

or multiple a fixed interval with the number of seconds:

```
interval '1 second' * :seconds
```

Both assumes that the parameter `:seconds` is an integer